# Duda con Programacion .NET Generar una Carta de Word a partir de C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-forms

necesito crear una programación que me genere un documento en word, me encontre con estos métodos pero no se como llamar el archivo de Word (ya tengo la plantilla en Word hecha). ¿Como hago para llamar esa plantilla de word dentro de esos métodos? Alguien me puede dar una sugerencia de como lo hago, muchas gracias

```
   private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp, Object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchsoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_Only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                    ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                    ref matchWildCards, ref matchsoundLike,
                    ref nmatchAllForms, ref forward,
                    ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                    ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                    ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                    ref matchControl);




    }

    string pathImage = null;

    private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object savaAs, object image)
    {
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        string tempPath = null;
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();

        Word.Document aDoc = null;

        if (File.Exists((String)filename))
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;
            wordApp.Visible = false;
            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            aDoc.Activate();

            //Find and replace
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<name>", "juan martin");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El archivo no existe");
        }
        //Save as : filename
        aDoc.SaveAs2(ref savaAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        //Close Document:
        aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        File.Delete(tempPath);
        MessageBox.Show("Carta Generada");

    }
```

Comment: en que contexto estan esos metodos? digo estan dentro de una clase o estan denro del form

Comment: Están dentro de una clase

Comment: entonces lo primero que tienes que hacer para acceder a al funcionalidad es cambiar el private por public de esos metodos, sino aunque instancies no podras accederlos

Comment: en este link creas el documento word y usando una plantilla https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316384/how-to-automate-microsoft-word-to-create-a-new-document-by-using-visua